# how can i convert data from a URL to xml

Tags: java, xml

How can I convert data from a url address to xml in java?
For example I want to load the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drama and the result returns in xml.

Comment: What do you mean by "the result returns in XML"?  Do you mean you want to translate HTML to XML?  What if the HTML is not well-formed?

Comment: yes,exactly!i want to return something like that http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xml&titles=Francis_Ford_Coppola

Comment: That's Wikipedia-specific.  That's nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: i gave an example..i want to convert an http file to xml so then i can parse it..

Comment: You cannot do that in general.  Your example "works" because the Wikipedia software has an API which outputs Wiki markup content in an XML format.  But this is not true of websites in general.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in their [Error response here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php), you need to send in the **format** query parameter to **xml** to retrieve the data in XML format. And the data contained within the **rev** element seems to be following the wiki syntax.

Comment: really help me with that link...so i just need the xml format!!! thank you very much!!